# java financial year wise sum Of Amount

Tags: sql, group-by, db2

I am stuck with a query to fetch sum of transaction amount financial year wise.
My table is

```
TXN_DATE    TXN_AMOUNT
12/01/2014  100
12/08/2014  200
12/01/2015  300
12/04/2015  400
12/04/2013  500
```

I want the result to be displayed as

```
FinYear         Amount
2013-2014       600
2014-2015       500
2015-2016       400
```

Considering financial year duration from 1st April of an year to 31st March of next year.

Databse DB2

Date is timestamp in database and date format specified in the example is dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Too many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: DB2  databse  is currently used

Comment: Does 12/01/2014 mean December 1st, or 12 of January?

Comment: No the date format is dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: Is the `TXN_DATE` column actually character, or is it date like it should be?

Answer (score 0):

Following query should do (tested in DB2 LUW):

```
with temp as (finyear, txn_amount) as (
select case 
         when month(TXN_DATE)< 4 Then year(TXN_DATE)-1 || '-' || year(TXN_DATE)
         else month(TXN_DATE)>= 4 Then year(TXN_DATE) || '-' || year(TXN_DATE)+1
      end as finyear,
      txn_amount
  from test4)
select finyear,         
       sum(txn_amount) as sum_amount
  from temp
 group by finyear;
```

Comment: Will ignore indices.

Comment: @clockwork-muse well the requst was to sum amounts right? There is no WHERE condition specified to filter anything. So tell me which index would you like to use (and how) in such a case?

Comment: `GROUP BY` is also allowed to use indices when it does the bucketing.  It also helps it estimate query cost and thus plan execution.  Granted, yes, since we're going over all the rows this is less of an issue, but good style should still be adhered to.  You could potentially get it use an index starting with the date if you could turn it into a range query (start and end dates).

Comment: Not working for me --- Getting an error -Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-104;42601;finyear|with temp as (|<values>, DRIVER=3.59.81
SQLState:  56098
ErrorCode: -727

Answer (score 0):

SELECT FinYear, cast(sum(Amount) as decimal(16,2)) AS Amount FROM 
(SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN TXN_DATE > to_date(year(TXN_DATE) ||'-03-31','YYYY/MM/DD')  THEN CONCAT(CONCAT(year(TXN_DATE),'-'),year(TXN_DATE)+1)
WHEN TXN_DATE < to_date(year(TXN_DATE) ||'-04-01','YYYY/MM/DD')  THEN CONCAT(CONCAT(year(TXN_DATE)-1,'-'),year(TXN_DATE))
END as FinYear, 
Amount AS Amount
FROM tab1) 
GROUP BY FinYear

Answer (score -1):

You can use following query:

```
SELECT FinYear, sum(Amount) AS Amount FROM 
(SELECT FinYear = 
CASE 
WHEN TXN_DATE > char(year(TXN_DATE)) +'0331' THEN char(year(TXN_DATE))+'-'+char(year(TXN_DATE)+1)
WHEN TXN_DATE < char(year(TXN_DATE)) +'0401' THEN char(year(TXN_DATE)-1)+'-'+char(year(TXN_DATE)) 
END, 
TXN_AMOUNT AS Amount
FROM DB2.Transactions) AS Table1
GROUP BY FinYear
```

Make sure you replace DB2.Transactions with your DatabaseName.TableName

Comment: Not working!--Getting error Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-104;42601;=|ROM 
(SELECT FinYear|CONCAT, DRIVER=3.59.81
SQLState:  56098
ErrorCode: -727